# Traveling from US to Canada

Tags: visas, canada, us-citizens

I am a US citizen travling to Venice, Italy with a connecting flight in Canada.  Do I need a travel visa or other documentationto pass through Canada?

Answer (score 3):

Your US passport is all you need.  No visas or anything are needed for a US citizen to enter Canada for transit or visiting.  You don't even need an eTA, which most other nationalities do.

http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1116&top=16

> You do not need a Canadian passport, a Canadian visa or an eTA to enter Canada if you are travelling with a valid U.S. passport.

Have a nice trip!